# Help in understanding a certain group theory proof

Tags: group-theory

The proof I do not understand is the proof to statement (2). Below I describe exactly what my problem is.

[image]

He shows that $n$ divides $im$, or equivalently $\frac{im}{n} \in \mathbb{Z}$. This is fine, I understand this. The particular part I don't understand is the following: he claims that $\frac{n}{\textrm{hcf}(i,n)}$ divides $m$. It seems to me this doesn't follow, for the following reason:

$$\frac{m}{\left(\frac{n}{\textrm{hcf}(i,n)}\right)} = \frac{im}{\left(\frac{in}{\textrm{hcf}(i,n)}\right)} = \frac{im}{n} \frac{1}{\left( \frac{i}{\textrm{hcf}(i,n)} \right)}$$

The $im/n$ is an integer, $i/\textrm{hcf}(i,n)$ is an integer, but there is no reason to think that their ratio is an integer. So I don't understand why $\frac{n}{\textrm{hcf}(i,n)}$ divides $m$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that $\frac{im}{n} \in \mathbb Z$. Suppose $im  = nk$. Let $d = \gcd(n,i)$. We know that $d$ divides both $i$ and  $n$, say $i=ad$, $n=bd$.

Furthermore, since $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $i$ and $n$, it follows that $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ otherwise if  there was something common between them we could have multiplied that quantity with $d$ to get a larger divisor of both $i,n$.

Then, substituting into the earlier equation gives $adm = bdk \implies am = bk$. Now, $b$ divides $am$. But, $\gcd(a,b) = 1$, so it follows that $b$ must divide $m$, since it doesn't share any factors with $a$, so it can only share all its factors with $m$.

But, $b = \frac nd = \frac n{\gcd(n,i)}$, so clearly this is a divisor of $m$.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac n{hcf(n,i)}\not | i$, for if it did, we would have a common factor of $n \text { and } i$, which doesn't divide $hcf(n,i)$...  a contradiction...

Note:  $\frac n{hcf(n,i)} \not | hcf(n,i)$ because then $n$ would have a factor which is not accounted for in $hcf(n,i)$...